# What happens if I remove a Javascript Script from the document head via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What happens if I remove a Javascript Script from the document head via Javascript?

Suppose I add a Javascript like this

```
var e = document,
        a = e.head || e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    script = e.createElement("script"), script.async = 1, script.src = t, a.appendChild(script)
```

It start running, adds listeners, variables, etc

Suppose I now remove the script using RemoveChild() or unset it

**What happens** to the listeners, variables etc? Are they all unset, removed etc (as if the script were never loaded?)

Comment: nothing happens, once loaded it's unused.